# Submitting Answer Fails with Email Required Message

Tags: bug

I'm trying to submit an answer on my own question on DBA but I'm showing an error in the console if I examine the request.

> {"success":false,"errors":{"Email":["An email is required to post."]},"warnings":{},"source":{}}

If this is expected behavior I would expect the DOM to have updated with some sort of messaging saying to login, or verify my account (which I thought was verified). I'm logged in and was able to post my question < 12 hours ago. Is this a bug or new behavior?

That JSON is from the action that loads `https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213718/answer/submit`.

My question is/was: [Master DB Ran Out Of Space](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213718/master-db-ran-out-of-space)[image: screenshot showing logged in]

Comment: And you have an email defined in your profile settings?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, just verified in the account settings, https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/147147 displays my email. It also says `These settings affect` and shows the Stack Overflow page, I've never had issues posting there..maybe it relates to a self-answer?

Comment: hmm..... maybe some old account you had and was merged into your current account? You remember having such account?

Comment: I don't recall merging accounts. If I did it was over 3 years ago.

Comment: Well... try logging out and logging in again. If no luck, try different browser or Guest/Private session of Chrome which don't use previous cookies.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Just tested answering on Stack Overflow and that works so I guess it is something with either my DBA account or the DBA code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51632399/3783243

Comment: Logging out and back in brought up a human verification block. After verifying that it let me post. Maybe it's my DSL connection..

Comment: Really weird.... well, hopefully now it works and you won't have to go through all of this when posting a new answer again. :)